# PKCE vs DCR for OAuth2 and Mobile Applications

Tags: oauth-2.0, oauth

I’m developing my own OAuth2 + OpenID Connect implementation. I am a bit confused about how to handle OAuth flows for native (specifically, Mobile) clients. So far, I am seeing that I need to use an Authentication Code Flow. However, based on my research, there are some details that seem to contradict each other(at least based on my current understanding).

First, standard practice seems to say that mobile apps are not inherently private and, as such, standard flows that make use of a back channel should not be used. As a work around, the PKCE extension can be used (and utilize the built-in device browser as opposed to a web view so the tokens and sensitive information are less likely to be leaked).

However, under the Protocol’s Dynamic Client Registration specification, it is also mentioned that mobile apps should use this method of client registration to get a valid client ID and client secret...  But, why would we do this when in an earlier section it was established that mobile applications were indeed public clients and couldn’t be trusted with confidential information like a client secret (which we are getting by using this DCR mechanism...

So, what am I not understanding? These two things seem to contradict one another. One claims mobile apps are public shouldn’t be trusted with a secret. Yet, in the recommended DCR mechanism, we assign them the secret we just established they can’t be trusted with.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit late, but hope it helps. So part of the OAuth2.0 protocol is two components, the client_id, and client secret. The client and server must agree on those two values outside the protocol i.e. before the protocol start. Usually, the process is as follows. The client communicates with the Authorization Server using an out-of-bound communication channel to get these values and be registered at the server. There is two way this client registration can happen, statically and dynamically. Statically mean the client_id and secret do change, i.e. the client gets them once when he registers with the server. Dynamic client registration refers to the process of registering a client_id every time the client wants to use to protocol, i.e. a client secret will be generated for him every time (also by an outbound communication).

**Now, Why use dynamic registration?**

Dynamic client registration is better at managing clients across replicated authorization servers., The original OAuth use cases revolved around single-location APIs, such as those from companies providing web services. These APIs require specialized clients to talk to them, and those clients will need to talk to only a single API provider. In these cases, it doesn’t seem unreasonable to expect client developers to put in the effort to register their client with the API, because there’s only one provider.

**Does Dynamic Client registration offer any security advantages?**

No, both are vulnerable if used with a JavaScript or a Native Mobile Client (JavaScript client can be inspected, and Mobile apps can be decompiled). Hence, both of them require PKCE as an extra layer of security.

Comment: Thanks. This helps clear things up. :)